# Need alternative of NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: nsurlconnection, xcode7, ios9

I want to do some task synchronously as :

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

is deprecated what I can use in place of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dispatch_sync` to perform synchronously tasks.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

      NSLog(@"Required task code.");
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
      // Update UI in main thread. 
      // Add your UI Label Update code here..
     }); 
  });
```

Let me know if you need anymore help..

Comment: But in this I can not add a NSMutableURLRequest I need this to check if server is taking too long to respond .

Comment: Can not add NSMutableURLRequest means?

Comment: I were trying to do something like this :
 
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
 
   NSData* urldata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

Comment: Are you calling GET OR POST method api?

Comment: Add below code in sync method,      NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];

Comment: But NSURLSession is asynchronous process and I am printing UILabel after completion of NSURLConnection . And in NSURLSession it is not refreshing the UILabel on the StoryBoard and also crashing alot of times.

Comment: Do your Label updatig task on main thread..  Not on another thread.    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //update UI in main thread.
            });

Comment: I am not putting it under any other thread just for testing purpose I have kept all this code under viewDidLoad under NSURLSession .

Comment: Yes but NSURLSession task performed on another thread, Which is not main thread. All UI related task should be performed on main thread.

Comment: So now how I can sort the things than ?
Can you please give me any suggestion because the text to be print is downloading through NSURLSession ?

Comment: I just updated my answer.. Please look into it & let me know if you still need anymore help for the same.

Comment: So can I add NSURLSession under dispatch_sync ?

Comment: Yes, If you put under dispatch_async then also it will work.

Comment: dispatch_sync not waiting for NSURLSession to complete its thread , so I am having same result as before. Same blank UILabel .

Comment: After few seconds this error : "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

Comment: It's a different issue. It's issue of setting constraints wrongly.. But your main job is done, correct??

Comment: Yes but as soon as UILabel appears it shows me that message and application crashes , same were happening using NSURLSession without dispatch_sync / async . Anyway my issue is soved I have used a library "NSURLSession-SynchronousTask".

Thanks for giving your precious time to understand and sort my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using "NSURLSession-SynchronousTask" library produces me same results as NSURLConnection .